# QuerySet.__str__ = __new_str__が必要な理由

Tags: python, django

`QuerySet.__str__ = __new_str__` って何故必要なのでしょうか？
これがないと表示されません。

Comment: 質問記事が短すぎて、どのようなプログラムの何処にそうした記述があって、何が問題なのかが明確で無いと思われます。こちらのヘルプ記事等を参考に詳細化してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765) 検索すると該当の記述はこんな書籍 [Python Django 4 超入門 （単行本）](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/book/9784798062419.html) の 201 ページにあるようですが、質問があればそのリンクに出版社の問い合わせ・感想窓口へのリンクがあるので直接問い合わせてみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 2):

たぶん, ソースコードには `QuerySet` という名のクラスが存在するのでしょう
(django よくは知らないけど, [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/) があるので, `QuerySet` クラスが用意され利用されてるのかも)

---

#### 特殊メソッド

(docs.python.org) [データモデル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html): [特殊メソッド名](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) より

> クラスは、特殊な名前のメソッドを定義して、特殊な構文 (算術演算や添え字表記、スライス表記など) による特定の演算を実装できます。これは、Python の演算子オーバロード (*operator overloading*) へのアプローチです。これにより、クラスは言語の演算子に対する独自の振る舞いを定義できます。

`object.__repr__(self)`

> [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#repr) 組み込み関数によって呼び出され、オブジェクトを表す「公式の (official)」文字列を計算します。可能なら、これは (適切な環境が与えられれば) 同じ値のオブジェクトを再生成するのに使える、有効な Python 式のようなものであるべきです。できないなら、 `<...some useful description...>` 形式の文字列が返されるべきです。戻り値は文字列オブジェクトでなければなりません。クラスが [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) を定義していて [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) は定義していなければ、そのクラスのインスタンスの「非公式の (informal)」文字列表現が要求されたときにも [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) が使われます。
>
> この関数はデバッグの際によく用いられるので、たくさんの情報を含み、あいまいでないような表記にすることが重要です。

`object.__str__(self)`

> オブジェクトの「非公式の (informal)」あるいは表示に適した文字列表現を計算するために、 [`str(object)`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) と組み込み関数 [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#format), [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print) によって呼ばれます。戻り値は [string](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) オブジェクトでなければなりません。
>
> [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) が有効な Python 表現を返すことが期待されないという点で、このメソッドは [`object.__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) とは異なります: より便利な、または簡潔な表現を使用することができます。
>
> 組み込み型 [object](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#object) によって定義されたデフォルト実装は、 [`object.__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) を呼び出します。

例えばこのように使うことができます
(最後の実行結果に注目)

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x}, {self.y})>'

p = Point(10, 20)
print(p)
# (10, 20)

display(repr(p))
# <Point(10, 20)>

def fn(self):
    return f'クラス {self.__class__.__name__}: 値は ({self.x}, {self.y})'

Point.__str__ = fn
print(p)
# クラス Point: 値は (10, 20)
```

質問のコードでは, `__new_str__` が (どこかで定義した) 関数と思われ

```py
QuerySet.__str__ = __new_str__
```

これらの何れかでなにか分かるかもしれません(関数だということが分かる程度？)

```py
print(__new_str__)
print(type(__new_str__))

help(__new_str__)
print(__new_str__.__doc__)
```